# jQuery tools tooltip, position with absolute & margin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tools

I'm using the jquery plugin: [Tools.tooltip()](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) Seems like the positioning is really a problem.

When the tooltip is wrapped in some container with position:absolute, you'll need to add `relative:true` in the conf dictionary so the tooltips are positioned properly.

Now the problem is: if you have both a `position:absolute` wrapper as well as tooltip triggers with margin, the position will be messed up

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<style>
.trigger
{
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip 
{
    display:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:#333;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
</style>
<div class='wrapper' style='position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px'>
    <div class='trigger' style='margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px'>
        hover to see the tooltip
    </div>
    <div class='tooltip'>
        The awesome tooltip
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.trigger').tooltip({
        position:'bottom center',
        relative:true,
    });
</script>
```

The tooltip is supposed to show beneath the trigger and centered in this case. But when mouse over the trigger(red box), tooltip(gray box) is showing at this position:

[image]

As if the margin is totally ignored. Also, if I don't use margin at all(only having a wrapper of position:absolute and uses relative:true in conf), the tooltip still shows up in a strange position:

[image]

The tooltip is a little bit to the left and top comparing to the correct position, which I have no idea about.

How may I solve this problem? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: How is the position messed up? Is the tooltip positioned relative to the `.trigger` or `.wrapper`? Is you could provide a working example or something to illustrate the extend of the problem, that would be nice. Cuz' I'm thinking, that using the `offset` property of the tooltip library would solve some issues.

Comment: I just edited it a bit and put in some pictures in hope it looks more clear. If using offset, I need to specify it of every different margin, which is not good for me.

Answer (score 2):

So if anyone wants to use jQuery tool tooltip:

- If the tooltip is wrapped in a 'position:absolute' or
  'position:fixed' container, supply 'relative:true' with the ini
  configurations.
- In this case, don't add any margin to the trigger of the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

I've made you a little fiddle, which "kindda" solves your problem.

In this fiddle, the tooltip gets places beneath your trigger, but it takes x number of "hovers" to get it 100% correctly placed. I'm thinking this is caused by some (mal)function in the tooltip library.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gjw74/1/

And the modified javascript:

```
$('.trigger').tooltip({
    position:'bottom center',
    relative:true,
    onShow: function(){
        var $trigger = this.getTrigger();
        this.getTip().css({
            'margin-top' : $trigger.css('margin-top'),
            'margin-left' : $trigger.css('margin-left') 
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hi Thor! I just figured out that if I remove 'margin:5px' from the trigger's css it's all going to be right. Thanks anyway! Seems like jquery tool tooltips are so bad at handling margins and positioning. They need to fix the problem, or at least document these limitations in an obvious way